# How to add an object from the first vector of pointer to second vector of pointer? C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, stl, smart-pointers

Declaring the vector of objects in this way...

`std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Boid> >m_flock;
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Boid> >m_flock2;`

And this is how I created my objects in a loop

```
    //Create objects in first container
    m_flock.resize(2);
    for(auto &boid : m_flock)
    {
        boid = std::shared_ptr<Boid>(new Boid);
        boid->setPos(20);
        std::cout<< boid->getPos() <<std::endl;
    }

    //Create objects in second container 
    m_flock2.resize(3);
    int num = 0;
    for(auto &boid2 : m_flock2)
    {
        num +=10;
        boid2 = std::shared_ptr<Boid>(new Boid);
        boid2->setPos(num);
        std::cout<< boid2->getPos() <<std::endl;
    }
```

This is the main part i need help with.. how do I properly compare the values of objects in first container and object in second container?

```
// Compare 2 objects function from one container to another
// If it's 2nd object container's value is equals to the value of the first container,
// Then add this to the first container.
// And erase that specific element in the 2nd container

    int i=0;
    for(auto &boid : m_flock) //Container 1
    {
        for(auto &boid2 : m_flock2) //Container 2
        {
       //If they are the same position, then push_back to container 1.
            if( boid2->getPos() == boid->getPos() )
            {
              //Push object of 2nd container to 1st container
                m_flock.push_back(boid2); 

             //Delete the object that was being pushed into the 1st container.
                m_flock2.erase(m_flock2.begin()+i); //Also is this the best way to delete that specic object?

                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
```

So now when I run into problems get a segmentation fault. Can someone please advise me? Thank you.

Comment: `m_flock2.erase(m_flock2.begin()+i)` looks yucky. Is there really an element there to be erased?

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying a container just as you are iterating over it. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want `std::partition` or, if the order of elements matters, `std::stable_partition`. Something like this (untested):

```
auto middle = std::partition(m_flock2.begin(), m_flock2.end(),
  [&](const std::shared_ptr<Boid>& boid2) {
    return m_flock.end() == std::find_if(m_flock.begin(), m_flock.end(),
      [&](const std::shared_ptr<Boid>& boid) {
        return boid->getPos() == boid2->getPos();
      });
  });

// Now in m_flock2, elements between begin() and middle don't match any
// in m_flock, while elements between middle and end() all do.
// Move the second half over to the end of m_flock, then erase from m_flock2

m_flock.insert(m_flock.end(),
               std::make_move_iterator(middle),
               std::make_move_iterator(m_flock2.end()));
m_flock2.erase(middle, m_flock2.end());
```